# Show Duplicates except the first value, when using Excel Tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I want to check for duplicate values in Veh Trx ID column, and give a TRUE if it repeats (except for the first value), and if they are all unique values then display FALSE. I have already managed to do it when using traditional Excel formula in Col A: =COUNTIF($H$3:$H3,H3)>1.

[image]

The problem arises because I have to now use table headers, so I changed my formula in Col A to: COUNTIF(Ops_Table[@[Veh Trx ID]:[Veh Trx ID]]: Ops_Table[[Veh Trx ID]:[Veh Trx ID]],Ops_Table[[Veh Trx ID]:[Veh Trx ID]])>1

It does indicate the duplicate Veh Trx ID with value of TRUE, but I wanted the first duplicate to still say FALSE, and the following duplicates to remain TRUE.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OFFSET:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(Ops_Table[[#Headers],[Veh Trx ID]],0,0,ROW($ZZ1)+1),[@[Veh Trx ID]])>1
```

[image]

Comment: I have been toiling behind this for 2 hours now, and you just solved it in an instant. Thanks a lot Scott. I appreciate your help.

Comment: After the question is 15 minutes old, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.